# How to place this text in HTML?

Tags: html

In the following screenshot, I would like to add a href which re-directs to a particular link between the `refresh` button and the `Need Help?` Button, however, when I use `<span>`, it doesn't work. It places it in the next line. How can I do it?

The HTML code for the screenshot is as follows:

```
<div class='modal-header'>
    <h3 class='modal-title' id='modal-title'>Deployment {{ctrl.ecsDeploymentDetails.number}} Details
        <a type="button" class="btn" ng-click="ctrl.refresh()" title="Refresh Events">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" ng-class="{'glyphicon-spin': ctrl.loading}"/>
        </a>
        <!--<h6><span class="well-small"><p>Please refer</p></span></h6>-->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right"
                ng-if="ctrl.supportRequired && ctrl.ecsDeploymentDetails.state === 'FAILED'" &&
                ng-click=ctrl.createAlert()>
            Need help?
        </button>
    </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you remove h6. Because  H tags will change the line or you can use class pull-left or style='float:left'

Comment: @ArsalanAkhtar I tried doing that, but the problem is, it is completely embedded in <h3> which increases its size to a very big text. I want to decrease this href size, and that's why I used h6. But even removing it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: <span class="well-small">Please refer</span>

Comment: I think p is also a line changer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code.

```
<div class="modal-header">
    Deployment {{ctrl.ecsDeploymentDetails.number}} Details
        <a type="button" class="btn" ng-click="ctrl.refresh()" title="Refresh Events">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" ng-class="{'glyphicon-spin': ctrl.loading}">
            </span>
        </a>
        <span class="well-small" style="font-size: 10pt">Please refer</span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right" ng-if="ctrl.supportRequired &amp;&amp; ctrl.ecsDeploymentDetails.state === 'FAILED'" &&="" ng-click="ctrl.createAlert()">
            Need help?
        </button>
</div>
```

Comment: But how can I reduce the text size?

Comment: I think you are trying to reduce the size of `Please refer`.

Comment: Yes, how can I do that?

Comment: @Qirohchan I have updated the answer. Please let me know if any queries.

Comment: You can change `10pt` to your desired size.